# How to add Header - Authorization for swagger 3, spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-2.0, swagger-3.0

I am using swagger 3, I want to add Authorization with "Bearer token" to call this api. I consulted with chatGpt and was instructed to add "@Parameter(name = "Authorization", description = "Bearer token", required = true, in = ParameterIn.HEADER)" but it doesn't work properly, can someone guide me?

```
@Operation(
        description = "Create post, USER/ADMIN",
        responses = {
                @ApiResponse(content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = PostResponseDTO.class)), responseCode = "200")})
@ApiResponses(
        value = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "200"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "401", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorDTO.class))),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "403", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorDTO.class))),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "404", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorDTO.class)))
        })
@PostMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')")
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = @Content(
        mediaType = "multipart/form-data",
        schema = @Schema(implementation = FormUpload.class)
))
@Parameter(name = "Authorization", description = "Bearer token", required = true, in = ParameterIn.HEADER)

public PostResponseDTO createPost(
        @Valid @RequestPart("post") PostRequestDTO postRequestDTO,
        @RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile[] file) throws IOException {
   
    if (!(filesService.notEmpty(file) && filesService.isSingleFile(file) && filesService.isImageFile(file[0]) && filesService.maxSize(file[0], 5))) {
    }
    return postService.save(postRequestDTO, file);
}
```

This is Swagger UI
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to define the security scheme in your swagger configuration
you can do it with the annotation `@SecurityScheme`

```
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "Authorization",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        bearerFormat = "JWT",
        scheme = "bearer"
)
public class SwaggerConfiguration {...}
```

After you set the security scheme then in your api you can define the security requirement for the following endpoint with `@SecurityRequirement`.

```
@SecurityRequirement(name = "Authorization")
public class PostController {...}
```

Make sure the security requirement match with the security scheme you set before. Here is the quote from the following github documentation about the security requirement.

> The name used for each property MUST correspond to a security scheme
> declared in the Security Schemes under the Components Object.

You can also change the hardcoded string to your defined constant variables.

Here is the reference [link](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/)